# Using $_GET to retrieve mycustomvariable

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to use the $_GET operator in php to get mycusomvariable from an fb app url to try to append a username, and find that this appears to return no details?

As an example here is the url I'm posting to Facebook:

**http://apps.facebook.com/my-app-namespace?username=Test**

and here is the php code which should retrieve the string 'Test'

```
    <?php

      $username = $_GET ['username'];
      echo $username;

    ?>
```

This should show up in the browser as Test, but shows nothing.

Anyone any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I notice a space betwee $_GET and ['username'].. Remove it just to be safe :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you possibly running a *old* version of PHP, the `$_GET` command was added in PHP 4.1.0. Try a `<?php  phpinfo(); ?>` to get your current version.

Have a look at the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) which shows version numbers.

Comment: @alfasin the op said it doesn't show up in his browser :- "This should show up in the browser as Test, but shows nothing."

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['username'])){
echo " fine" ;
else { 
echo "not set" ;
```

And search google for url variables

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename variable `username` to something else. Maybe Facebook has blocked that variable name.
Example:
`http://apps.facebook.com/my-app-namespace?qwerty=Test`

```
<?php
  $username = $_GET ['qwerty'];
  echo $username;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know facebook applications are running in the `<iframe>`. If it is true, then you can not get access to the global $_GET array in your application.